# jax lax way to roll arrays given an variable axis index

Tags: python, jax

Is there any way to roll arrays within a jax compiled method such that the axis along which the array is rolled is a variable? For example, the following code:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

A = jnp.ones((4, 4, 4, 4))

indList = jnp.asarray([0, 1, 2])

def roll(ind):
    return jnp.roll(A, -1, axis=ind)

result = jax.lax.map(roll, indList)
```

Yields the following error:

> `ConcretizationTypeError`: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: traced array with shape `int32[]`.
> expected a static index or sequence of indices.

As far as I can tell, the `@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums = 0)` decorator to the `roll` method would not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `lax.map` requires its arguments to be dynamic, and you cannot use `jnp.roll` with a dynamic axis because it is built on primitives that require the axis to be static.

One way to work around this is to dynamically construct indices that will extract the desired result; for your case the approach might look like this:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def roll_dynamic(ind):
  assert len(set(A.shape)) == 1, "roll_dynamic requires all dimensions to be equal."
  indices = jax.lax.broadcasted_iota('int32', (A.ndim, A.shape[0]), dimension=1)
  indices = jnp.where(jnp.arange(A.ndim)[:, None] == ind,
                      jnp.roll(indices, -1, axis=-1), indices)
  return A[tuple(jnp.meshgrid(*indices, indexing='ij', sparse=True))]

def roll(ind):
  return jnp.roll(A,-1,axis=ind)

A = jnp.arange(256).reshape(4, 4, 4, 4)
indList = jnp.asarray([0, 1, 2])

for ind in range(4):
  assert jnp.all(roll(ind) == roll_dynamic(ind))

result = jax.lax.map(roll_dynamic, indList)
```